# " unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)" RSpec 3, Rails 4.1.6, Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to spec out a `Users` controller, using **RSpec 3.1.7**, and I keep getting the `unexpected end-of-input SyntaxError`. I ended up "stripping" the entire controller to the first `describe`, just to see which line is causing the issue, like so:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do

end
```

Here is the exact error:

```
[my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': [my app path]/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
 from [my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
 from [my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
 from [my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
 from [my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
 from [my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
 from [my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
 from [my app path]/spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
 from [my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
 from [my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
 from [my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
 from [my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
 from [my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
 from [my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
 from [my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
 from [my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
 from [my ruby path]lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
 from [my ruby path]bin/rspec:23:in `load'
 from [my ruby path]bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Here is my `rails_helper.rb`:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'ffaker'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Factory_Girl Init
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # DatabaseClener config
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

and here is my 'spec_helper.rb'

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

I'm running:

- Ruby 2.0
- Rails 4.1.6
- RSpec 3

Comment: The syntax error is in the controller file, not the spec.

Comment: In the error message we could see: [my app path]/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:20: syntax error. Have you check your user controller (around line 20). Maybe a 'end' missing.

Comment: oh, boy...I am such a noob. Of course... Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax error appears to be in your controller file, not the controller spec or the spec helper.

```
/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

You can check the syntax of an individual file using the `-c` ruby flag.

```
$ ruby -c app/controllers/users_controller.rb 
Syntax OK
```

The output will either declare the syntax to be OK, or will give you an error message similar to what you are currently receiving.